# I need to join the two tables in the following way.. using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, dbms-job

**Table 1**

```
Country Export 
China     90
India     80   
Korea     40
```

**Table 2**

```
Country Import 
China     40
India     30   
Japan     50
```

**Result**

```
Country Export Import
China     90     40
India     80     30
Korea     40     0
Japan     0      50
```

Comment: This is a full outer join. Examples of replicating this in MySQL are discussed widely.

Comment: use FULL OUTER JOIN and then COALESCE to replace the nulls with 0.